# Error installing phonegap via npm on Mac OS X

Tags: cordova, npm

Reading the phonegap documentation they recommend to install phonegap via npm using the commnad:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

However I'm getting the following error in the console>

```
MacBook-Pro:$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm ERR! TypeError: uid must be an unsigned int
npm ERR!     at Object.fs.chown (fs.js:853:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.chown (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:131:17)
npm ERR!     at endChown (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:212:12)
npm ERR!     at setProps (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:295:5)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:286:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/mark
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.14
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mark/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Watching the npm-debug.log shows additional info:

```
43 info postuninstall phonegap@3.0.0-0.14.0
44 verbose tar unpack /Users/mark/.npm/phonegap/3.0.0-0.14.0/package.tgz
45 silly lockFile f38db7ac--local-lib-node-modules-phonegap tar:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap
46 verbose lock tar:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap /Users/mark/.npm/f38db7ac--local-lib-node-modules-phonegap.lock
47 silly lockFile 97de6b36-honegap-3-0-0-0-14-0-package-tgz tar:///Users/mark/.npm/phonegap/3.0.0-0.14.0/package.tgz
48 verbose lock tar:///Users/mark/.npm/phonegap/3.0.0-0.14.0/package.tgz /Users/mark/.npm/97de6b36-honegap-3-0-0-0-14-0-package-tgz.lock
49 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
50 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry package.json
51 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .npmignore
52 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry README.md
53 error TypeError: uid must be an unsigned int
53 error     at Object.fs.chown (fs.js:853:11)
```

I get a very similar output when I try to install cordova cli using this mechanism.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've installed other packages via npm successfully such as express and socket.io without any issues so I'm assuming my node.js install is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with node version 0.10.14 but was fixed at 0.10.15 as can be seen here: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3703